# Variable names in AS2 #

Tags: variables, actionscript-2

Can I use the # sign in AS2 variable names?

like ->> var item_#_productName = "test"

I must use a list of preset varilable names but I am getting a syntax error when I use the # sign.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you are stuck with #, you can try omitting var and use:

set:

```
this["item_#_productName"] = "test";
```

get:

```
return this["item_#_productName"]; // returns "test"
```